# Do I have to cast if I malloc for an array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Just a quick question I couldn't find a question on:

```
double* array = (double*) malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(double));
```

or can I simply

```
double* array = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(double));
```

is there any difference?

Comment: you don't cast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Your question asks for C, so do not add C++ tag. C is not C++ and this is one of the differences between the languages.

Comment: array is a pointer and not an Array. Malloc's return type is VOID*, so no, there is no need to CAST malloc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, you *shouldn't* cast since it can hide certain subtle errors. In C++ (since your question originally had that tag despite no mention in the body), you *have* to cast.

The "subtle errors" of which I speak include strange behaviour when your integers and pointers are different sizes and you haven't included the header for `malloc` - in that case, you may find it assuming it returns an `int` (losing information in the process) and, while the compiler would normally warn about that, the explicit cast will probably prevent that.

Comment: Out of curiousity, which "subtle errors" can this hide?

Comment: @JoelCornett Failure to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @dbush Any decent compiler would warn for that.

Comment: Ah, the 'no _true_ Irishman' argument :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo *cough* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman

Comment: Note: in C++ you might as well just use `new`.

Comment: Actually in C++ you should not use C programming style and not use `malloc` & friends. Btw. The rule can be generalised in C: do not cast to/from `void *` in C. The only exception are variadic arguments if the callee expects a `void *` like the `printf` family.

Comment: Since C99 the compiler must give a diagnostic, even if the cast is present

Comment: @arduic, that's _one_ variant, I believe the Irish one is another. Of course the Scot one is more prevalent so I probably should have used that.